# Exclude multiple inputs from serializeArray

Tags: jquery, arrays, serializearray

I have a form with some inputs, selects, and checkboxes. I am unable to exclude the items with class "not_included" in my serialized Array.

```
var dataArray = $("#split_form").not(".not_included").serializeArray();
```

This still is serializing the fields with class "not_included".

Thanks!

Comment: It would be much easier (and safer) to do this check at serverside rather than clientside.

Answer (score 3):

To filter the `<input>`s within the `<form>`, you'll have to first [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) a collection of [them](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/):

```
$('#split_form').find(':input').not('.not_included').serializeArray();

// or
$('#split_form').find(':input:not(.not_included)').serializeArray();
```

[`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) only applies filtering to the elements directly within the `jQuery()` collection, which is presumably just the `<form>` based on the selector, `'#split_form'`.

It won't affect their children or descendants. So, it's just determining whether the `<form>` is either:

```
<form id="split_form"></form>
```

```
<form id="split_form" class="not_included"></form>
```

Comment: I am using class="not_included" for specific inputs.